# Exact sequence and finitely generated module

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, modules

It is a easy execise to show that: If $L,N$ are finitely generated modules over $A$ (commutative ring) and $0\to L\to M\to N\to 0$ is an exact sequence, then $M$ is a f.g. module.

Now, suppose that $L,N$ are f.g. modules over $A$ and $0\to L\to M\to N$ is an exact sequence. Is it $M$ a f.g. module?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take the case $L=0$. Then if $0\to M\to N$ is exact, and $N$ is finitely
generated, then is $M$ also finitely generated?

Not necessarily, if $A$ is non-Noetherian, since then $A$ has a non-finitely generated ideal.

But if $A$ is Noetherian, then $M/L$ is isomorphic to
a submodule of $N$, so finitely
generated. From this and the finite generation of $L$ it follows that
$M$ will be finitely generated.